# Magento 2: Description Not showing in category products widget added in CMS page

Tags: magento2

I have added a widget to my cms page which shows products of the category.

```
{{widget type="Magento\CatalogWidget\Block\Product\ProductsList" title="BREAKFAST" show_pager="0" products_count="10" template="Magento_CatalogWidget::product/widget/content/grid.phtml" conditions_encoded="^[`1`:^[`type`:`Magento||CatalogWidget||Model||Rule||Condition||Combine`,`aggregator`:`all`,`value`:`1`,`new_child`:``^],`1--1`:^[`type`:`Magento||CatalogWidget||Model||Rule||Condition||Product`,`attribute`:`category_ids`,`operator`:`==`,`value`:`3`^]^]"}}
```

Product show name, price, image, but it does not show description of Products.
 this file is used there.

```
  app\design\frontend\Smartwave\porto_child\Magento_CatalogWidget\templates\product\widget\content\grid.phtml
```

and here is the code of this grid.phtml file

```
    <?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

?>
<?php
/**
 * Template for displaying products list widget
 *
 * @var $block \Magento\CatalogWidget\Block\Product\ProductsList
 */
?>
<?php if ($exist = ($block->getProductCollection() && $block->getProductCollection()->getSize())):?>
<?php
$_productCollection = $block->getLoadedProductCollection();
$_helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');
$_imagehelper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image');

$_category_config = $this->helper('Smartwave\Porto\Helper\Data')->getConfig('porto_settings/category');
$_category_grid_config = $this->helper('Smartwave\Porto\Helper\Data')->getConfig('porto_settings/category_grid');
?>
<?php
    $type = 'widget-product-grid';

    $mode = 'grid';

    $image = 'new_products_content_widget_grid';
    $hover_image = 'category_page_grid-hover';
    $title = $block->getTitle() ? __($block->getTitle()) : '';
    $items = $block->getProductCollection()->getItems();
    //print_r($items);exit;

    $showWishlist = true;
    $showCompare = true;
    $showCart = true;
    $templateType = \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ReviewRendererInterface::DEFAULT_VIEW;
    $description = true;

    $image_width = ($_category_config['ratio_width'])?$_category_config['ratio_width']:300;
    $image_height = ($_category_config['ratio_height'])?$_category_config['ratio_height']:300;
?>
        <?php if ($title):?>
            <div class="col-sm-6 p-l">
                <h2><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $title; ?></h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-9">
        <?php endif ?>
            <?php $iterator = 1; ?>
            <?php foreach ($items as $_item): ?>
            <!--  -->
                <div class="col-sm-6 p-l">
                    <div class="img-box">
                        <a href="<?php echo $_item->getProductUrl() ?>" class="product-modal-btn product-modal-btn-top">
                            <div class="img-box-outer">
                                <?php
                                if($_category_config['aspect_ratio'])
                                $productImage = $_imagehelper->init($_item, $image)->constrainOnly(FALSE)->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)->keepFrame(FALSE)->resize($image_width);
                                else
                               $productImage = $_imagehelper->init($_item, $image)->resize($image_width, $image_height);
                               $productImageUrl = $productImage->getUrl();
                                ?>
                                <img src="<?php echo $productImageUrl?>" alt="<?php echo $productImage->getLabel(); ?>">
                            </div>
                        </a>
                        <div class="text-box">
                            <h3><?php echo $block->escapeHtml($_item->getName())?></h3><span><?php echo $block->getProductPriceHtml($_item, $type)?></span>
                            <p><?php echo $block->escapeHtml($_item->getDescription())?></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
            <!--  -->
            <?php endforeach ?>
    <?php echo $block->getPagerHtml()?>
<?php endif;?>
```

if the 9th last line you can see i am using escapeHtml($_item->getDescription())?> which is showing nothing. Can you provide me the code which will show description here.

Comment: try with - var_dump($_item);  to check which data you get in array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This piece of code worked for me in showing Description of Product.

```
<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($_item->getShortDescription())?>
```